# Possibility taking values from base constructor whose variables are different from the variables in derived constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

It's a bit different to explain what I want but I hope that I can explain the way you can understand.

I have a class A (the main class)

**class B : A (inheritance)**

**class C : A**

Class A has got my own written constructor like this:

```
public A(int a, int b, int c, string d)
{
}
```

Let's see class B:
Class B inherits from class A.
Here I'd like to write an another individual constructor which has more possibilities than the other from A.

It looks like this:

```
public B(int a, int b, int c, string d, int e)
{
}
```

Now the compiler will probably return an error because the standard constructor in class A has been deleted. So, I have to write like this:

```
 public B(int a, int b, int c, string d, int e) : base(a, b, c, d)
    {
       /* It's working because I've added the variable "e" only.
       The other variables haven't been changed. */
    }
```

But what about this situation?
Class C which doesn't have to do anything with class A also wants to have its own constructor. It looks like this:

```
 public C(int w, int x, string y, string z) : base(a, b, c, d)
    {
         /* Class C does have completely different values than class A.
            But I'd like to have all the variables the way I've written above.
            I'd like to use variable "w" for example. But "a" should be valid 
            to use as well. How is it possible to make the variables
            a, b, c and d valid to class C? */
}
```

I hope you understand which problem I'd like to be solved.

Comment: _you_ need to tell us what problem you would like to be solved. what is your goal, what have you tried, and what errors did you get

Comment: Your C example doesn't make any sense.  If C doesn't have a,b,c or d defined in the constructor arguments, where do you expect the compiler to get these values?

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. I create an object in Class Main and there the values are transferred and the constructor of Class A is called. These values a=13, b=14, c=15, d="I don't know how to explain better!" should be transferred to Class C somehow. Then it looks a bit like the code from Alexei Levenkov but he has initialized in class C. Instead of values it should be variables.

Comment: Any chance that you expect `new C(...)` somehow pick arguments from completely unrelated separate call to `new A(...)`? Sample code that you want to see working may be useful....

Answer (score 2):

There is really no magic to pass values from outside to base class constructor - derived class must somehow specify all arguments to base constructor either passing directly or computing in some other way. Usually you'd compute parameters of base constructor from arguments and some constant values:

```
 public C(int w, int x, string y, string z) : 
       base(w+x, x*3, 42, "Test:" + y+z) {...}
```

---

Below is answer to code puzzle interpretation of the question:

> how to make `public C(int w, int x, string y, string z) : base(a, b, c, d)` compile irrespective of result"

To be able to compile `base(a, b, c, d)` which are not passed as arguments you need them to be static fields/properties or `const` values visible in the derived class (i.e. defined in derived class with any accessibility or defined in base class with non-private accessibility). You can't use instance fields/properties as parameters of base constructor per C# specification (reasoning: there is really no "instance" at that point).

Sample that would let code to compile (you can also move any of a,b,c,d to base class with `public`/`internal`/`protected` access modifier):

```
class C : A 
{
  static int a = 42; // static value, initialization is optional 
  static int b {get;set;} // static property ok, with default 0 value
  const int c = 44;
  const string d = "Why?";

  public C(int w, int x, string y, string z) : base(a, b, c, d) {...}
  ...
```

Comment: Okay, this is good. Let's see this: My values are in class A. In Class Main where the main method is I'd like to transfer the values like 42, 43, 44 and "Why?". Then the values are like this for example:                                                       public A(42, 43, 44, "Why?")
{
}                            I don't like to write the values in class C because it's not flexible any more. All the values are written in Class Main whether I create an object and transfer the values to the constructor.

Comment: @LuckyBuggy your question feels like "how to make `public C(int w, int x, string y, string z) : base(a, b, c, d) ` compile irrespective of result" - I have no idea what your actual goal is.

Comment: @slugster also note that static fields/properties can stay implicitly initialized with default values (you get warning, but not error for that).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sample of code might help you helping me ;-).

First of all, I'm jumping into the main method. Then an object of class B is created by using following code:

```
new B(global::Test.Properties.Resources.MyPlane, 100, 100, 200, 100, 10, 10);
```

Then I'm coming to the constructor of B with following arguments (no execution yet):

```
public B(Bitmap pathOfMovingObject, int xPositionObject, int yPositionObject, int widthOfObject, int heightOfObject, int tank_size, int life)
            : base(pathOfMovingObject, xPositionObject, yPositionObject, widthOfObject, heightOfObject)
```

Then it's coming to the constructor of A with following arguments:

```
 private PictureBox picBoxImage;     
    protected Bitmap path;
    protected int x, y, width, height;
```

**If I change the instance variables to static like this, then it's working but I can't create two instances of class B any more:**

```
protected static Bitmap path;
protected static int x, y, width, height;
```

If I change the static variables to instance variables again, then I've got the problem that this error report appears:

An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'A.path'.

```
    public A(Bitmap pathOfMovingObject, int xPositionObject, int yPositionObject, int widthOfObject, int heightOfObject)
        {
            path = pathOfMovingObject;
            x = xPositionObject;
            y = yPositionObject;
            width = widthOfObject;
            height = heightOfObject;

picBoxImage = new PictureBox();
            picBoxImage.Image = pathOfMovingObject;
            picBoxImage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            picBoxImage.SetBounds(xPositionObject, yPositionObject, widthOfObject, heightOfObject);
            this.Controls.Add(picBoxImage);
        }
```

Then the constructor of B is called and the code in the block is executed.

Then I'm jumping back to main class with main method. Object of class C is created.

```
new C(1000, 650, 5, "stackoverflow", global::Test.Properties.Resources.sky);
```

Then I'm coming to C constructor (no execution yet).

Then I'm jumping to constructor of the class A and the block is executed.

Then I'm coming to C constructor again:

```
public C(int width, int height, int speed, string title, Bitmap path)

    : base(path, x, y, width, height)  -- There you can see the error...
```

An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'A.path'.

**So, my question is... how is it possible to create two instances of class B which are displayed on the screen either and to set the values valid in class C and to disable the upper error report?**